# Can't pass local variable with collection partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I have the following in my view:

```
<%= render :partial    => "greetings/greeting",
           :collection => @greetings,
           :locals     => { :board => @board }
%>
```

In my partial I have the following:

```
if greeting_is_for_manager?(greeting, board)
```

However I can't access the `@board` that was passed as board because I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `board' for
  #<#<Class:0x0000010420cf38>:0x000001041f9b90>):
```

I passed in the local `board`--What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the rest of your partial look like?

Comment: inside your partial you should declare board = locals[:board], before use it

Comment: If do board=locals[:board] inside my partial I get an error: undefined local variable or method `locals' for #<#<Class:0x0000010461d730>:0x0000010461aa08>

Comment: Jordan the rest of my partial works perfectly when I use the @board instance variable directly.  I tried what Kav1nsky suggested but got an error.